# Error adding MVC project as a reference in another

Tags: .net, preferences

I have a very big project with few controllers and I want to divide it into 2 projects, and add project 2 as a reference in project 1.

I've copied the project and cleaned all not necessary controllers, js, cshtml exc.
The same I did in the first project, deleting the controller that is in the new project.
Then I'd added the new project dll as a reference in the first project.

but now I get an error when running the main project (project_1):

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request.
Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: The type 'XXX.MvcApplication' is ambiguous: 
it could come from assembly 'project2\xxx\bin\project2.DLL' or from assembly 'project1\bin\project1.DLL'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="XXX.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

What shold I do now???

Comment: That looks like a line from global.asax, not an error message. What's the actual error message? Is that in the main project or the new one you've separated out?

Comment: OK, so you have two different classes called XXX.MvcApplication, one in each project? ASP.NET can't work out which one it should be using. You're not planning to run the second project as a website without the first project's code are you? Why do you need two versions of XXX.MvcApplication?

Comment: The first project is very big. It has lots of classes, models, controllers, css exc...  When I try to change project_2 project name it doesn't wok at all.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you try to change a project name. I'm suggesting you make sure you don't have duplicate classes called XXX.MvcApplication in both projects.

Comment: Should I jest change the name of the class or delete it?

Comment: What's in the duplicate copy? Do you need it? If it has logic specific to the code that you've separated out into Project2 then you'll probably need a way for Project1's MvcApplication class to call it. If it's just a complete duplicate and you're not planning to run Project2 as a separate site in isolation without Project1 then you can probably just delete it.

Comment: OK, thanks I'll try to delete it and let you know!

Comment: Thanks! it's working now!!!

Comment: How do I call the controller in the referenced project?

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure sorry: I don't remember how ASP.NET MVC discovers controllers. If everything's in the same namespace it might work but I guess it doesn't: you'll probably just have to register the new assembly at the point you set up routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/243245/rup.

The problem was that in both projects I had Global.asax.cs file.
When deleting the file from the referenced project it is running!!!